# Can someone explain this function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning about `call` and `apply` in javaScript from a online TUT. This function allows more arguments to be passed, rather than having a fixed amount.

```
var calculate = function(){
        var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
        return fn.apply(null, arguments);
    };
```

What I am having difficulty wrapping my head around is this statement.

```
var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
```

The presenter of the of the TUT, explained it as the following:

We are binding the `apply` method onto the `arguments` object. This is going to give us the `Function Object` and assign it to the fn variable. It will also remove the `Function Object` from the `arguments`Object. Because the Array's `pop method` takes the final element in the array, it removes it from the Array and then assigns to what ever called the method. In this case the `fn` variable.

What confused me was the following:

> We are binding the `apply` method onto the `arguments` object. This is
>   going to give us the `Function Object`
>
> It will also remove the `Function Object` from the `arguments`
>   Object.

And when we write in the return statement:

```
 return fn.apply(null, arguments);
```

Why are we including `null`?

Comment: this code doesnt validate any way i call it

Comment: in `apply`, the first arguments is the context (the `this`). In `Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments)`, you're using `arguments`, which is an array-like object (NOT an actual `Array` object), as the context. That's because you can't do `arguments.pop()`, because `arguments` doesn't share `Array.prototype`... it's not actually an `Array` object.

Comment: So in the first `apply`, you don't need the second argument. However, in `fn.apply(null, arguments)`, you're passing in `null` as the first argument, because there's no need for a context. But, you pass in `arguments` as the second parameter because it can be used by the function.

Comment: I don't know why people keep closing this question...

Comment: arguments is pseudo-array, calling pop on it (get last element = function), then running it on rest of arguments. calculate(1,2,3,4,5,function() { console.log(arguments); });

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);`

When you have a function, there's automatically an `arguments` objects, which is an Array-like object of arguments. If you call this fake function:

```
someFunction('hello', 'world');
```

and `someFunction` looks like this:

```
function someFunction() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

The `console.log` will output `['hello', 'world']`. However, don't be confused... That is not an `Array` object! It is an "array-like" object. Therefore, you can't say `arguments.pop()`... because `arguments` doesn't have that method (it belongs to `Array.prototype`). However, normal `Array` objects **do** have access to `Array.prototype` (e.g. `[1,2,3].pop() // => [1,2]`).

When you say `.apply()`, the first argument is the context... It sets the `this`. So really, `Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments)` is a clever way of mimicking `arguments.pop()`. But you can't do `arguments.pop()`, because it doesn't have a `pop` method.

In `return fn.apply(null, arguments);`, `null` is the first arguments because we don't need to set a new context for this example. `arguments` is the second arguments because it's being passed in to use with `fn`.

`.apply()` returns a function object, so it returns something like this:

```
function() { ... }
```

We can then later invoke that function.

By the way, `.pop()` mutates the original object (in this case, the array-like object `arguments`). So you're passing in `arguments` to `fn`, but it's missing the last item that was in it previously.

Answer (score 1):

The last argument passed to `calculate` is assumed to be a function. It is popped from the `arguments` list. (Using `apply` because `arguments` is not a real array.)

This popped function (`fn`) is called with the rest of the `arguments` list. (All other arguments passed to `calculate`). The  `arguments` list no longer contains `fn` because `pop()` modifies the original object.

`NULL` is used because `fn` is called without a value for *this*. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

---

If you call `calculate` for instance like

```
calculate(2, 3, function(a, b){ return a + b });
```

it will return 5.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> ## Syntax
>
> fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
>
> ### Parameters
>
> thisArg:
> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, **null and undefined will be replaced with the global object**, and primitive values will be boxed.
>
> argsArray:
> An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which fun should be called, or null or undefined if no arguments should be provided to the function. Starting with ECMAScript 5 these arguments can be a generic array-like object instead of an array. See below for browser compatibility information.